# Why won't the navigation stay for all pages except the home page?

Tags: html, css

I actually have two related issues here.  When I scroll down I would like the orange navigation to say on top of the page.  It works well with all other pages, except the home page.  I am somewhat confused with the positions and z-index aspects.  Second I would like to have the active text of the page the user is on to be #000000.

/****************   top navigation ********************/

```
#nav {
width:  100%;
position:  relative;
text-align:  center;
z-index:  999;  
height:  63px;
background:  #ED8A39; }

#nav.affix {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
min-height: 50px;
z-index:10;
} 


#nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;  }

#nav ul {
padding: 0;
margin:  0 auto;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;  }

#nav ul:after {
content: ""; clear: both; display: block;  }

#nav ul li {
float: left; }

#nav ul li:hover {
background: #ffffff;  }

#nav ul li:hover a {
color: #ED8A39;  }

#nav ul li a {
display: block; 
padding: 22px 8px;
color: #ffffff; 
margin:  0;
text-decoration: none;    }

#nav ul li active {
    color: black;  }

.nav-container  {
width:  100%;
font-size:  13px;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0 auto;  }
```

```
   <div class="nav-container">
    <ul>          
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="family_planning_clinics.html">FAMILY PLANNING 
       CLINICS</a></li>
    <li><a href="healtheducation.html">HEALTH EDUCATION</a></li>    
    <li><a href="breast_cervical_clinics.html">BREAST &amp; 
       CERVICAL CANCER</a></li>
    <li><a href="primary_health_care.html">PRIMARY HEALTH CARE</a></li>
    <li><a href="natural_fam_planning.html">NATURAL FAMILY PLANNING</a></li>
    <li><a href="immunizations.html">IMMUNIZATIONS</a></li>
      </ul>
          </div>

     </div><!-- close nav-->
     </div>

     <div class="cycle-slideshow" style="position: relative; z-index:  -1;">
       <img src="assets/img/slide-family-planning.jpg" 
         width="100%" alt="family planning clinic" />
       <img src="assets/img/slide-health-education.jpg" 
         width="100%" alt="health education clinic" />
       <img src="assets/img/slide-breast-cervical-cancer.jpg" 
         width="100%" alt="breast cervical cancer" />
       <img src="assets/img/slide-primary-health-care.jpg" 
         width="100%" alt="primary health care" />
       <img src="assets/img/slide-natural-family-planning.jpg" 
         width="100%" alt="natural family planning" />
       <img src="assets/img/slide-immunizations.jpg" 
         width="100%" alt="immunizations" />
    </div>
```

Comment: If you want reliable answer, put one working demo. Run these codes you put here on jsfiddle.net and check it, cause it's not matching your question.

Comment: I am so sorry.  working demo is at http://jandswebsitedesigns.com/family/

Answer (score 0):

Find below line in your home:

```
<div id="nav" class="navbar" style="margin-bottom:  0; padding-bottom:  0;   border-radius:  0;">
```

Change it to:

```
<div id="nav" class="affix">
```

This will activate sticky-on header.

About the color change you want, use `a:active {color:#000000}` but keep this order in CSS file:

first:   `a:link`

second: `a:visited`

third:   `a:hover`

fourth:   `a:active`

Comment: thanks for you help ata!  I did what you suggested.  This is what happened.  the navigation moved to the top of the page and is stuck there.  Click here to see what I mean http://jandswebsitedesigns.com/family3.  also since  I am trying to use an ul listing for the navigation.  I am somewhat confused about where to use the a:active {#000000}

Comment: Try this change `class="affix"` to `class="affix-top"` and call `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` in your home page. About color change, I'm not sure because I'm not good at jQuery reading, but I think `bootstrpa.min.js` has something to do with active links and won't allow CSS changes. Again I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I am sorry that change did not work.  I will try to debug it jandswebsitedesigns.com/family3